# ListView sort column by Label control ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am attempting to sort a ListView column by a control content - in this case a Label, as opposed to within the SQL itself. This is due to a calculation in the C# code behind to display the text in the column of the LV ItemTemplate.

The control content is a Date displayed value (UK short date format).

So in code terms, if the label is:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbDateSort" Text='<%# CalculateDate() %>' />
```

I'd like the ListView (i'd hazard guess on LV DataBound) to, by default, sort by the resulting value in the Label example.

I hope that makes sense, but happy to clarify further. Thanks a load guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing CalculateDate() logic and sorting before binding data to ListView. For example:

Let's assume you need to calculate delivery dates of items based on their order date.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Item Name: <asp:Label ID="lblItemName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ItemName") %>' /></br>
        Order Date: <asp:Label ID="lblOrderDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OrderDate") %>' /></br>
        Delivery Date: <asp:Label ID="lblDeliveryDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DeliveryDate") %>' /></br>
        </br>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Code behind you call CalculateDeliveryDate(DateTime orderDate) method to figure out the delivery date and update the collection. On assigning data source to ListView you can sort the collection how you want.

```
public partial class ListViewExample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var data = new List<ListModel>
        {
            new ListModel { ItemName = "Phone", OrderDate = new DateTime(2017,1,12) },
            new ListModel { ItemName = "Book", OrderDate = new DateTime(2017,1,1) },
            new ListModel { ItemName = "Desk", OrderDate = new DateTime(2017,3,12) }
        };

        data.ForEach(x => x.DeliveryDate = CalculateDeliveryDate(x.OrderDate));

        ListView1.DataSource = data.OrderBy(x => x.DeliveryDate);
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }

    private DateTime CalculateDeliveryDate(DateTime orderDate)
    {
        return orderDate.AddDays(7);
    }
}

public class ListModel
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
}
```

Your result will look like

Item Name: Book

Order Date: 1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM

Delivery Date: 1/8/2017 12:00:00 AM

--

Item Name: Phone

Order Date: 1/12/2017 12:00:00 AM

Delivery Date: 1/19/2017 12:00:00 AM

--

Item Name: Desk

Order Date: 3/12/2017 12:00:00 AM

Delivery Date: 3/19/2017 12:00:00 AM

Comment: Thanks Shahid, so basically populate a list with the resulting dataset and order that. Good call, and definitely worth a try. thanks again

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to close the question if it was answered.